# flex 4: how to apply css to <span> in TextArea

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

there is a TextArea

```
<s:TextArea id="TextView"/>
```

in script is a function where written:

```
TextView.textFlow = TextFlowUtil.importFromString("some <span fontWeight="bold">bold</span> text.");
```

it's works, but... i need something like this:

```
<span class="test">
```

and then

```
<fx:Style>
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

 s|TextArea span .test {
      fontWeight: bold;;
    } 
</fx:Style>
```

how to do it?  Thanks in advance!